# How to insert only if not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, insert

I am trying to insert data in table, but if it already exists in table, then it should not add.
This is the code, what I came up, but it still adds multiple data with same values.

```
insert into nol_art_izm([ART_ID],[DAT])
    select distinct
        v.id_art, {fn now()}
    from
        openxml(@hDoc, '/art_kompl/nol_voac') with #vc xd
        inner join nol_voac v on xd.id_art = v.id_art
    where
        not exists(select * from nol_art_izm where nol_art_izm.art_id=xd.id_art)
```

I want that there aren't any duplicate "ART_ID" values

Comment: Your query seems fine to me. Do you get duplicates in `select distinct` part? My version of sql server gets the value of now() once, but I'm not sure it is always the case.

Comment: @Nikola It inserts duplicate "ART_ID" values in the table

Comment: You might consider in this case doing a `GROUP BY v.id_art` and choosing an aggregate function for `{fn now()}` (for example, `max`).

Comment: @w0lf And what will that GROUP BY do?

Comment: the `GROUP BY` clause ensures that you get every `v.id_art` value *one time*, regardless of how many `{fn now()}` values it is associated with

Comment: please see the edit to my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
insert into nol_art_izm([ART_ID],[DAT])
    select distinct
        v.id_art, {fn now()}
    from
        openxml(@hDoc, '/art_kompl/nol_voac') with #vc xd
        inner join nol_voac v on xd.id_art = v.id_art
        left join nol_art_izm n on n.art_id = v.id_art
    where n.art_id is null
```

**Update:**

Try using `GROUP BY` to avoid duplicate `id_art` values:

```
insert into nol_art_izm([ART_ID],[DAT])
    select
        v.id_art, MAX({fn now()})
    from
        openxml(@hDoc, '/art_kompl/nol_voac') with #vc xd
        inner join nol_voac v on xd.id_art = v.id_art
    where
        not exists(select * from nol_art_izm where nol_art_izm.art_id=xd.id_art)
    group by v.id_art
```

Please not that I have chosen the `MAX` function for aggregating the `{fn now()}` values (in case there are more such values per `id_art`). You might want to use another function.

Comment: In unprobable cases, joining could be worse than the OP's semi-join, as there is a risk of further data duplication if there are already duplicates in `nol_art_izm.art_id`

Comment: @LukasEder You are right about that. Your `MERGE` solution looks perfect, thanks for sharing it. +1

Answer (score 7):

**Note**: This answer will only work with SQL Server 2008...

Use the [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb510625.aspx) statement. The advantage of a `MERGE` statement is the fact that it clearly expresses the intent of wanting to insert only if there is not yet a match. For future readers, this might be helpful, as alternatives involving `INSERT .. SELECT` are a bit more tricky to decipher.

```
-- This is where you're "merging" data into
MERGE INTO nol_art_izm dst

-- This is your merge data source
USING (
  -- Use DISTINCT here, to prevent possible duplicates from the below INNER JOIN
  SELECT DISTINCT v.id_art 
  FROM openxml(@hDoc, '/art_kompl/nol_voac') with #vc xd
  INNER JOIN nol_voac v on xd.id_art = v.id_art
) src

-- This is your "join" condition, used to decide whether to perform an
-- INSERT or UPDATE
ON (dst.art_id = src.id_art)

-- When source and target don't match (see ON clause), perform an insert
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ([ART_ID],[DAT])
  VALUES (src.id_art, {fn now()})
```

This statement omits the `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE` clause, as you're only interested in performing `INSERTs`, not `UPDATEs`

Comment: When I use your method, it shows me an error: "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure INSERT_UPDATE_ARTIKULS_KOMPLEKTS_XML, Line 574
Incorrect syntax near 'MERGE'." Can't figure it out why.

Comment: @Brezhnews: `MERGE` was introduced with SQL Server 2008. What version are you using?

Comment: Then that seems to be the problem, because I am using SQL Server 2005. Is there something similar in SQL Server 2005?